# What does the TopScoreDocCollector in Lucene by default use for Scoring?

Tags: java, sorting, indexing, lucene, scoring

I want to use Lucene to process several millions of news data. I'm quite new to Lucene, so I'm trying to learn more and more about how it is working.

By several tutorials throughout the web I found the class TopScoreDocCollector to be of high relevance for querying the Lucene index.

You create it like this

```
int hitsPerPage = 10000;
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
```

and it will later collect the results of your query (only the amount you defined in hitsPerPage). I initially thought the results taken in would be just randomly distributed or something (like you have 100.000 documents that match your query and just get random 10.000). I think now that I was wrong.

After reading more and more about Lucene I came to the javadoc of the class (please see [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopScoreDocCollector.html)). Here it says

> A Collector implementation that collects the top-scoring hits,
>   returning them as a TopDocs

So for me it now seems that Lucene is using some very smart technology to somehow return me the top scored Documents for my input query. But how does that Scorer work? What does he take into account? I've extended my research on this topic but could not find an answer I completely understood so far.

Can you explain me how the Scorer in TopcScoreDocCollector scores my news documents and if this can be of use for me?

Comment: Default score on lucene is based on tf.idf : (https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Lucene uses an inverted index to produce an iterator over the list of doc ids that matches your query.

It then goes through each one of them and computes a score. By default that score is based on so-called Tf-idf. In a nutshell, it will take in account how many times the terms of your query appear in the document, and also the number of documents that contain the term.

The idea is that if you look for (warehouse work), having the word work many times is not as significant as having the word warehouse many times.

Then, rather than sorting the whole set of matching documents, lucene takes in account the fact that you really only need the top K documents or so. Using a heap (or priority queue), one can compute these top K, with a complexity of `O(N log K)` instead of `O(N log N)`.
That's the role of the TopScoreDocCollector.

You can implement your own logic for a scorer (assign a score to a document), or a collector (aggregates results).

Answer (score -1):

This might be not the best answer since there is defently sooner or later someone available to explain the internal behaviour of Lucene but based on my days as a student there are two things regarding "information retrieval" - one is taking benefit of existing solutions such as Lucene and those - the other is the whole theory behind it.

If you are interested in the later one i recomend to take http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval as a starting point to get a overview and dig into the whole thematics.

I personally think it is one of the most interesting fields with a huge potential yet i never had the "academic hardskills" to realy get in touch with it.

To parametrize the solutions available it is crucial to at least have a overview of the theory - there are for example "challanges" whereas there has information been manually indexed/ valued as a reference to be able to compare the quality of a programmic solution.

Based on such a challange we managed to aquire a slightly higher quality than "luceene out of the box" after we feed luceene with 4 different information bases (sorry its a few years back i can barely remember hence the missing key words..) which all were the result of luceene itself but with different parameters.

To come back to your question i can answer none directly but hope to give you a certain base to determine if you realy need/ want to know whats behind luceene or if you rather just want to use it as a blackbox (and or make it a greybox by parameterization)

Sorry if i got you totally wrong.